# Dagger 2, How to add interface in dependency

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I just started working with dagger 2. I have created dependency graph for application level dependency. Now that i wanted to create dependency that are required for a specific activity So i created another `Component` for activity then i created the Module and scope for that component. Now that when i am done writing all the code i build the project but i get compiler error which i am unable to solve.

Here is what i am doing.

```
@FeedsCatalogActivityScope
@Component(modules = FeedsCatalogActivityModule.class, dependencies = FeederApplicationComponent.class)

//My activity requires Catalog adapter so i am creating dependency for that
public interface FeedsCatalogActivityComponent {
    CatalogAdapter getCatalogAdapter();
}
```

Here is the Module

```
@Module
public class FeedsCatalogActivityModule {

    private final SelectedInterfaceListener selectedInterfaceListener;

    public FeedsCatalogActivityModule(SelectedInterfaceListener selectedInterfaceListener) {
        this.selectedInterfaceListener = selectedInterfaceListener;
    }

    @Provides
    @FeedsCatalogActivityScope
    public CatalogAdapter catalogAdapter(Picasso picasso, SelectedInterfaceListener mSelectesInterfaceListener) {
        return new CatalogAdapter(picasso, mSelectesInterfaceListener);
    }

}
```

Here is the scope

```
    @Scope
public @interface FeedsCatalogActivityScope {
}
```

So now when i build i get this error

> /Users/Zeeshan/Desktop/personal/Feeder/app/src/main/java/io/droidninja/feeder/FeederApplication.java
>   Error:(10, 31) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerFeederApplicationComponent
>   /Users/Zeeshan/Desktop/personal/Feeder/app/src/main/java/io/droidninja/feeder/ui/activities/FeedsCatalogActivityComponent.java
>   Error:(13, 20) error: io.droidninja.feeder.ui.adapters.SelectedInterfaceListener cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
>   io.droidninja.feeder.ui.adapters.SelectedInterfaceListener is injected at
>   io.droidninja.feeder.ui.activities.FeedsCatalogActivityModule.catalogAdapter(…, mSelectesInterfaceListener)
>   io.droidninja.feeder.ui.adapters.CatalogAdapter is provided at
>   io.droidninja.feeder.ui.activities.FeedsCatalogActivityComponent.getCatalogAdapter()
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

What i am understanding is that i have problem in `FeedsCatalogActivityModule`. How should i provide `SelectedInterfaceListener`? It is a interface.

P.S i am new to dagger2 i just get started with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, you are suppose to pass an instance of `SelectedInterfaceListener` to `FeedsCatalogActivityModule`  when your are building `FeedsCatalogActivityComponent` inside the activity that uses it.

in your activity create a method that setup the component like this

```
private void initializeInjector() {
    FeedsCatalogActivityComponent feedsCatalogActivityComponent = DaggerFeedsCatalogActivityComponent.builder()
            .feederApplicationComponent(feederApplicationComponent()/* create this method and it should return a correctly built  FeederApplicationComponent */ )
            .feedsCatalogActivityModule(
                new FeedsCatalogActivityModule(
                    new SelectedInterfaceListener() 
                    /* pass in the instance of SelectedInterfaceListener here */ )
                ).build(); 
}
```

And then remember to change the Module provides method to

```
@Provides
@FeedsCatalogActivityScope
public CatalogAdapter catalogAdapter(Picasso picassor) {
    return new CatalogAdapter(picasso, this.selectedInterfaceListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you must somehow provide an implementation for that interface. Take a look at:

- [@Binds](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Binds.html)
- [@Provides](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Provides.html)
- [Binds vs. Provides](https://google.github.io/dagger/faq.html)

Example

```
@Binds
abstract SelectedInterfaceListener provideDsListPresenter(SelectedInterfaceListenerImpl impl);
```

Comment: An Activity is implementing that interface. What should i do in that case?

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2#dependent-components-vs-subcomponents

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir  am wondering why you would want it to be implemented by an Activity, anyways checkout my answer and pass `this` as a reference in the module constructor when building the component.